# Is there a way to make context only re-render if its data changes?

Tags: reactjs, react-context, react-lifecycle, use-context

As depicted below, I have a basic react context setup.

My desire is child components consuming the context should only re-render when the context data changes, but I'm finding that's not the case.

If I update call `setData2`, which is not associated with the context, a state update is triggered on `Container` which subsequently triggers a recalculation and causes the consuming child to update.

The child component in question is already using `React.memo`, so it would only update if its `useContext` hook led it to. But the context gets updated when `Container` updates, even though `data1` is unchanged.

Is it possible to fix this?

```
const Container = () => {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(...);
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(...);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ data1, setData1 }}>
     // child component hierarchy
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To prevent child components re-rendering when context state changes, you should pass the child components into the context provider via the `children` prop:

```
// Define the provider component
const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(...);
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(...);

  return (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ data1, setData1 }}>
     {children}
    </MyContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Then somewhere in your app, render the provider:

```
// Render the provider component
const App = () => {
  return (
    <MyContextProvider>
     // child component hierarchy
    </MyContextProviderr>
  );
};
```

To access the provider state, a child should use the `useContext(MyContext)` hook.

There is no need to use `React.memo`. React knows that when rendering child components using the `children` prop, the child components do not need to be re-rendered, because it is impossible for them to be affected by local state change.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the child component that you do not want to be rerender (triggered by other unrelated state) in a `useMemo` with the related dependencies - only to that child

```
const Container = () => {
  const [data1, setData1] = useState(...);
  const [data2, setData2] = useState(...);

  const rerenderInCertainConditions = useMemo(() => (
    <MyContext.Provider value={{ data1, setData1 }}>
     // child component hierarchy
    </MyContext.Provider>
  ), [data1])

  return (
    {rerenderInCertainConditions}
  );
};
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit goofy-kare-wgn45]